# Mongodb change method of relations

Tags: mongodb

Im newbie in mongodb and considering various use cases before really use that. 
Consider that collection:

```
{
  "id": "item1", 
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}, 
{
  "id": "item2", 
  "tags": ["tag2", "tag4"]
}
```

Its simple implementation of relations. It works fine until I attach tags to one tyle of entries in database.

Imagine that I want to add new entry type in live system and I want to attach tags to that type. In "normal" database change of relations to separate tags into new table (tag | id, name) then create tables to connections (item_tag, item2_tag) is not do hard.

But hows achieve that operation in mongodb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine that I want to add new entry type in live system and I want to attach tags to that type

There's no need to change anything. You just create that new entry type (you mean a separate collection, correct?) and attach tags to it the same way you do now, embedded arrays.

Comment: OK, that correct. But if I will want to change name of tags from time to time ? It force me to create new collection with tags to avoid duplicating of data. As far as I good understand in case of elements which changing (ex names of tags) its better to make new collection for them ?

Comment: @webcitron: In case of tag rename, you can just remove old name and insert a new one.

Comment: So I have to loop over every relation with tag to rename and do renaming ? In normal databases its very bad performance, how it looks in mongodb ? And how to show tags cloud with that struct ?

Comment: @webcitron: no need for iterating manually, database will do it for you (`$pull`, `$push` operators). Tag cloud, on the other hand, is another problem entirely.

Comment: Show me Please an query to mongodb for example

Comment: Show me Please an query to mongodb for example to rename tag2 to tag10 based on struct above

Comment: @webcitron: it's two queries, 1) `db.foo.update({tags: 'tag2'}, { $push: {tags: 'tag10'}}, false, true)`, then 2) `db.foo.update({tags: 'tag2'}, { $pull: {tags: 'tag2'}}, false, true)`

Comment: Thanks Sergio, you was explain me a lot ! :)